# One trackpad gesture make Safari crash

Tags: safari, osx-lion

When I want to replace swipe laterally with two fingers (I don't know what the exact translation is) with the previous gesture (Snow Leopard's), the three-finger move, and then I try to use this in Safari, the app crashes immediately. It then displays the crash report which says there was an error with this plugin: AirKeysInputManager.
How can I solve this issue?

Also, do you know if it's possible to customize Mission Control's gesture? I'd like to swipe downwards instead of having to swipe upwards.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all your Input Manager hacks from `/Library/InputManager` and `~/Library/InputManager`. Uninstall SIMBL. Uninstall Unsanity's "Application Enhancer" (APE).

Application developers hate APE, SIMBL, and all Input Manager hacks because they can cause apps to crash and people don't realize it was the fault of some Input Manager hack the user had installed, and not the app's fault.